# Error converting data type varchar to int dynamic SQL select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sp-executesql

I am trying to execute `sp_executesql` inside a stored procedure. When I execute the stored procedure, it throws this following error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 0
>   Error converting data type varchar to int

I couldn't figure it out where the error occurs

Here is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spHoldTransaction] 
    @RegisterNo INT,
    @StoreID INT,
    @Department VARCHAR(50),
    @TransactionDateFrom DATE,
    @TransactionDateTo DATE,
    @Comment VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DatabaseName VARCHAR(15);

    IF (@StoreID = 5555)
    BEGIN
        SET @DatabaseName = 'xxx'
    END

    SET @Department=''''+REPLACE(@Department,',',''',''')+''''

    DECLARE @HoldEntryQry NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @HoldEntryParamDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @HoldEntryParamDefinition = N'@Department VARCHAR(50),@StoreID INT,@NewId INT,@TransactionDateFrom DATETIME,@TransactionDateTo DATETIME'    

    DECLARE @NewId INT;
    SET @NewID = 15;

    SET @HoldEntryQry = 'SELECT te.StoreID, ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @NewId) + ' AS TransactionHoldID,
                             te.ItemLookupCode,
                             item.Description,
                             te.ItemID,
                             SUM(te.Quantity) Quantity,
                             SUM(te.SalesTax) Tax,
                             SUM(te.Price * te.Quantity) Value,
                             SUM(te.Price * te.Quantity) / SUM(te.Quantity) Price,  
                             item.price FullPrice,
                             --1 AS Taxable,
                             GETDATE() AS TransactionTime,
                             ''1899-12-30'' AS VoucherExpirationDate
                         FROM
                             TransactionEntry te
                         LEFT JOIN
                             item ON item.id = te.ItemID
                         INNER JOIN
                             item nItem ON nitem.ItemLookupCode = item.itemlookupcode
                         WHERE
                             te.TransactionDate >= ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(@TransactionDateFrom AS DATE), 102) + 
                         ''' AND te.TransactionDate <= ''' +
                             CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(@TransactionDateTo AS DATE), 102) +
                         ''' AND item.department IN (' + @Department + ') 
                             AND te.storeid = ' + convert(varchar(max), @StoreID)+'
    group by
        te.StoreID,
        te.ItemLookupCode,
        item.Description,
        te.ItemID,
        item.price
   '
EXECUTE sp_executesql @HoldEntryQry, @HoldEntryParamDefinition, @NewId, @Department, @Storeid,@TransactionDateFrom, @TransactionDateTo 
END
```

When I do `Print @HoldEntryQry`, the query looking like below

```
 select 
    te.StoreID,
    15 AS TransactionHoldID,
    te.ItemLookupCode,
    item.Description,
    te.ItemID,
    sum(te.Quantity) Quantity,
    sum(te.SalesTax) Tax,
    sum(te.Price * te.Quantity) Value,
    sum(te.Price * te.Quantity)/sum(te.Quantity) Price,  
    item.price FullPrice,
    1 AS Taxable,
    Getdate() AS TransactionTime,
    '1899-12-30' AS VoucherExpirationDate

from
    TransactionEntry te
    left join item on item.id = te.ItemID
    inner join item nItem on nitem.ItemLookupCode = item.itemlookupcode
where
    te.TransactionDate >= '2018.04.16' and te.TransactionDate <='2018.04.30' and item.department in ('Apple','Orange','Dates') and te.storeid = 5555
group by
    te.StoreID,
    te.ItemLookupCode,
    item.Description,
    te.ItemID,
    item.price
```

The printed query is returning the exact result I expect

Comment: For starters you should ALWAYS specify the scale of varchar. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length Also you should use ANSI compliant date format of YYYYMMDD. Those periods in there will cause issues in some situations.

Comment: But the biggest question for me is why are you using dynamic sql here? From what you posted it is just a layer of complexity that is not needed.

Comment: @SeanLange are you talking about `voucherExpirationDate`. Please leave that one. And thanks for your concern

Comment: That is just a string that looks like a date. I was looking at your where clause.

Comment: @SeanLange I really needed. My case is entirely different. DatabaseName will not be same all the time

Comment: @SeanLange Even I remove complete `Where clause`, still it throws the same error. I am confirmed once again just now

Comment: So this isn't really your code then? You are adding the database name in your dynamic sql in the actual code. Without a bit more detail I don't see anything that is obviously the issue. My guess is that you have some datatypes mixed up in your tables.

Comment: @SeanLange This error is coming from the same query What I mentioned here.

Comment: Do you really mean to join item to itself on the same column? I would think maybe nitem.id?

Comment: Of course it comes from your query. But I can't see your tables or run anything. Can you share the ddl for those tables?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably `+@Department+`.  If *any* argument to `+` is not a string, you are probably going to get a conversion error.

But don't just do `cast(@department as varchar(255))`.  Fix the root cause of the problem.  You already know about parameters.  Use them for all the constants in the `where` clause!  This will make your debugging easier.